# Calling SQL Server 2008 stored procedure from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I am trying to call a stored procedure written in MS SQL SERVER 2008 from PHP ODBC through following code, but it does not seem to work:

```
$statement = odbc_prepare ( $con, "CALL take_snapshot(?)");
if ($statement !== FALSE) {
if (odbc_execute ( $statement, 2010) !== FALSE) {
   return true;
    }
}
```

In SQL server management studio I simply execute it by writing:
**exec take_snapshot 2010**
in query window and it works fine.

Can anyone guide me with correct syntax of call a procedure from PHP ODBC.

Comment: This should help, http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`odbc_execute` expects an array for the second parameter. You're passing an integer.

> ```
> odbc_execute ( resource $result_id [, array $parameters_array ] )
> ```

You should use:

```
 odbc_execute ( $statement, array(2010) )
```

[See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php)

Comment: OK. Thanks this worked but I ran into another error. Now it says: COUNT field incorrect or syntax error CALL take_snapshot (?)

Comment: @asim-ishaq Try to prefix it with the schema (ie `dbo.procedure`)

Comment: I just figured out the correct way of calling it. use: **exec dbo.take_snapshot ?**  Thanks for helping!